# Upload image button not firing

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have a upload image button  like this

ASP.NET

> ```
>      <asp:FileUpload ID="fulProduct" runat="server" CssClass="one-third-input"  onchange="Validate(this.id);" />
>       <asp:Button ID="BtnUploadImg" runat="server" CssClass="button round gray image-left ic-save" OnClick="BtnUploadImg_Click" Text="Submit Image"/>
> ```

and write a code to upload file (image file) to `ImageName` and `ImageEncrypt` like this
VB.NET

```
 Protected Sub saveimg(ByVal DocumentStatusID As Integer)
    Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    cmd.Connection = Conn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "spProducts"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", "UPDATE")
    Try
        If ((Not txtProducerID.Text.Trim = "") And (Not lblGetProductID.Text = "")) Then
            If fulProduct.HasFile = True Then
                Dim fileSize As String = fulProduct.PostedFile.ContentLength

                If (fileSize < 1024000) Then ' 1MB approx (actually less though)
                    'Upload new file
                    Dim EncryptName As String
                    pnlUpload.Visible = False
                    pnlSave.Visible = True
                    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fulProduct.PostedFile.FileName)
                    Dim fileExtension As String = Path.GetExtension(fulProduct.PostedFile.FileName.ToLower)

                    EncryptName = Encrypt.MD5(fileName & Now) & fileExtension
                    fulProduct.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/FileStore/" & EncryptName))
                    lblPicture.Text = "<img src='../FileStore/" & EncryptName & "' height='300' />"

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", fileName & fileExtension)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageEncrypt", EncryptName)

                    hplPictureView.NavigateUrl = "~/FileStore/" & EncryptName
                    hplPictureView.Target = "_blank"
                    chkPictureDelete.Checked = False
                End If

            ElseIf chkPictureDelete.Checked = True Then
                'Delete exist file
                Dim FileToDelete As String

                FileToDelete = Server.MapPath(hplPictureView.NavigateUrl)
                If File.Exists(FileToDelete) = True Then
                    File.Copy(FileToDelete, Server.MapPath(hplPictureView.NavigateUrl.Replace("~/FileStore/", "~/FileStore/Deleted/")))
                    File.Delete(FileToDelete)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", "")
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageEncrypt", "")
                End If
                pnlUpload.Visible = True
                pnlSave.Visible = False
            End If

            Conn.Open()
            Dim ResponseText As Integer = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar, Int32).ToString
            If (ResponseText = 1) Then
                lblResponseResult.Text = "<img src='../images/icons/message-boxes/confirmation.png' /> บันทึกลงฐานข้อมูลเรียบร้อยแล้ว"
                If (DocumentStatusID = 2) Then 'Goto next step
                    AlertRedirect("redirect", pnlHint.ClientID, 3, "Products.aspx")
                Else
                    AlertBox("alert", pnlHint.ClientID, 2)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
            sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
            sb.Append("javascript:history.back();return false;")
            sb.Append("};")
            sb.Append("</script>")
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "back", sb.ToString())
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("Error Save: " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        Conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

and create an Event

```
    Protected Sub BtnUploadImg_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    SaveProduct(1)
End Sub
```

but all of these button not firing it's just reset the fileupload field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add post back trigger and try..

```
<Triggers>  
     <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID = "BtnUploadImg" />
</Triggers>
```